# How to perform the limit of infinite time in the LSZ approach?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, s-matrix-theory

I am computing the scattering matrix using the LSZ reduction formula in a semiclassical limit. The result that I am getting has the following form:
$$
S = \lim_{t_i \to - \infty} \lim_{t_f \to \infty} f(t_i,t_f),
$$
where $f(t_i,t_f)$ is a function that is expressed in terms of a path integral and $t_i$ ($t_f$) is the initial (final) time from where I am evolving the scattering particle. That is, I am amputating the particle propagator by putting the initial and final points on-shell.

The problem that I am having is that I can write the function $f(t_i,t_f)$ in a closed form if I expand it perturbatively with respect to a small parameter. However, once I perform this expansion I obtain some terms of the form:
$$
\lim_{t_i \to - \infty} \lim_{t_f \to \infty} \frac{t_i+t_f}{2(t_f-t_i)}.
$$

My question is: Is this limit well defined? Can I solve it?

Because if I perform the limit at different orders I obtain a different result. Sending $t_f \to \infty$ first I obtain $1/2$ and $t_i \to - \infty$ first I obtain $-1/2$.

In some cases, I see the scattering matrix defined as:
$$
S_{fi}=\lim_{T \to \infty} \langle \psi_f | U(-T,T) |\psi_i \rangle,
$$
so I am tempted to just perfom the change of variables $T=t_f-t_i$ and $b=(t_i+t_f)/2$ and take the limit $T \to \infty$ at fixed $b$ in my expression, sol that the limit in my example is just $0$. However I am not sure if this is justifiable.